# How to change a cell in a datatable which is in a jquery dialog?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, datatables

So I have a unique dialog box opening which a click a button. Inside the dialog box, I have a data table (which is preloaded when the original page is loaded). Now what I want to do is to change a cell text when the user clicks a buttton in the jquery dialog. I gave the cell a unique id and everything, but for some reason I cant update the text in the cell from the call back in javascript. I have been able to do it without the dialog, but for some reason I cant do it in the dialog. Does anyone know why? The simple javascript im using is

```
document.getElementById('boldStuff_' id).innerHTML = 'gasgsadg';
```

Comment: @Nick The change was made in the php (where i render the datatable) to make it work..

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
document.getElementById('boldStuff_' + id).innerHTML = 'gasgsadg';
```

Notice the missing "+" which is used in this instance to concatenate the string with the value of **id**.

Comment: Sorry the + was just a typo.. but its not working.. It seems that the dom does not update..

Comment: We need to see more code then. The problem could be in many places.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there is the answer in case other people are having the same issue. Okay so basically all the popups are being written to the DOM, nd thus i was using the same ID for the rows in each popup. All i did was add a second identifier:

```
$('#groups_check_'+result[i]+'_'+grppk).addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-check');
```